# ASP.NET page using AJAX ScriptManager, UpdatePanel, UpdateProgress controls not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, scriptmanager, updateprogress

I'm working with a customers .NET application and trying to display text and gif animation 
while the page is doing a postback to the server. I originally created a separate project in the application solution, which used a simple button press to create a 5 second delay 
(to simulate the postback delay). After the delay, a label on the web page is updated with
the current time.

I'm using ScriptManager, UpdatePanel and UpdateProgress controls.
The separate project I created works fine but when I integrate the same code into the
customers existing project I can't get the UpdateProgress control to display the text or gif.

Here is the form code:

```
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager3" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
         <h1>UpdatePanel</h1>
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Generate Report" 
           onclick="Button1_Click" />
      </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <br />

    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress3" runat="server"
     AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel3">
    <ProgressTemplate>
           <h1>UpdateProgress</h1>
              <div class="PleaseWait">
                  Please Wait...
              </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>


    <h1>No update, just straight up text</h1><br>

  </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: are you receiving response?if i want ask better are you sure that button click is triggering?

Comment: yes the button click is triggering. There is a 5 second delay and the label is tied to a timestamp call which updates 5 seconds later after the button press.

Comment: maybe other library you have included in your project makes conflict in your code.and also check your overall stylesheet and make sure there is no role applied to your element inside UpdateProgress template.

Comment: Good idea, this software application is new to me so I'll have to do some digging and ask how/what/why all the various references are used in the project that the AJAX controls are not working correctly.